# Initialize variable in recursive function

Tags: java, variables, recursion, linked-list, initialization

I am making a recursive function that HAS TO HAVE NO parameters to get the length of a linked list.

```
public int lengthHelper() {
    if (first == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        first = first.next;
        return 1 + length();
    }
}
```

The problem is that by using first=first.next I will ruin first, first being my header. So I want to copy first within the function (instead of my ugly wrapper script) but recursion makes that a hassle. Any idea how to proceed?

Here's the wrapper btw, which I'd like to remove:

```
public int length() {
    Node temp = copy(first);
    int output = this.lengthHelper();
    first = copy(temp);
    return output;
}
```

The reason I have these limitations is because it's a personal challenge based on an assignment. Recursive + wrapper was sufficient, but ever since I've been thinking if it's possible to solve it any cleaner way.

Comment: Does the recursive method have to be no parameters?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `first` is the head of your list and is a private instance variable?

Comment: Yes and yes. No parameters allowed, and first is my head

Comment: Is `length` maybe supposed to be a method of the list class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly `first` is the recursive data structure `Node`, and in the non-recursive container class `List` (for instance) you need to define a recursive method (without parameters).

Then the solution is to have a method in `List` that yields a new List of the tail/rest, without `first`. Below I presume a constructor with a Node.

```
class Node { }
public class List {
    Node first;

    public int length() {
        if (first == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            List tail = new List(first.next);
            return 1 + tail.length();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is actually very similar to my answer below, the main two distinctions being (1) not breaking-then-fixing the list and (2) the temporary variable is on the stack for mine and in the heap (`new List`) in this solution. They're similar in that in both cases, you're creating a tail list (in this explicitly, in mine by modifying `this` to be its own tail), getting its length, and then discarding it (in this by letting `List tail` go out of scope, in mine by restoring `this).

Comment: @yshavit yes, I see you like algorithms and datastructures too. +1

Comment: Yup. :) I like your solution a tad more than mine, despite the fact that it'll churn through more objects. It's less code, thread-safe, doesn't risk breaking the list if there's a bug,  and keeps each list immutable. That last part actually makes things easier for the garbage collector, which could partially offset the cost of the extra objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty artificial requirement. :) But what about storing `first` in the local stack frame, and then restoring it before you return?

This sounds like a homework question, so maybe I shouldn't spill out the full answer. But it would basically be along the lines of:

- create a local variable to store the current value of `first`
- update `first`, thus breaking the list (as you pointed out)
- recurse down, and save the result from that recursion in a second local variable
- use that first local variable to restore `first`
- return the result from the second local variable

For extra credit, try to do this in a way that won't break the list if you happen to hit an exception (such as a stack overflow) in the process. Hint: `try-finally`.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I looked for

Comment: To be honest it was a homework question. My professor was satisfied with the ugly wrapper solution though. After that I couldn't stop thinking if there was a way to remove it. Personal challenge if you will.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way of doing this. I recommend something like this:

```
public int length() {
    return computeLength(this.first);
}
private int computeLength(Node node) {
    if (node == null) return 0;
    return 1 + computeLength(node.next);
}
```

Comment: It's still the same problem but it's a lot cleaner that what I did. Might settle for it unless someone has an eureka moment.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do without some form of parameter. By using a class variable to store recursion state (in your example the "first" object), you simply risk breaking it somewhere else. May I ask why you want to do this?